# js-cookie cookie value doesn't persist through refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a web page that has an advertisement on it. I'm using js-cookie to manage my cookies

[Link to JS-Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

When a user first navigates to our website, I want javascript to check for a cookie named `'advertisement'` and if it doesn't exist, to create one with the value of `'open'`

```
    //Check for cookie. if it doesnt exist, create it
    var cookie = Cookies.get("Advertisement");
    alert(cookie);
    if (cookie == "undefined" || cookie == null || cookie == "" || cookie == "null") {
        CreateCookieAdvertisement();
    } 

function CreateCookieAdvertisement() {
    alert("Creating cookie function");
    Cookies.set("Advertisement", "open");
}
```

The advertisement has a anchor tag that has a javascript function to set the value of `'Advertisement'` to `'closed'`

```
<a class="close" id="closeAdvertistement" onclick="CloseCookieAdvertisement()">&nbsp;</a>

function CloseCookieAdvertisement() {
    Cookies.remove('Advertisement');
    Cookies.set('Advertistement', 'closed');
}
```

Here is the problem. When I first load the site, it determines the value is undefined and creates the cookie with a value of `'open'`
[image: 1cookieOpen]

Then, after I close the advertisement, it sets the cookie to `'closed'`

[image: 1cookieclosed]

But after doing a refresh, for some reason it creates an additional cookie named `'advertisement'` with a value of `'open'` while the original `'advertisement'` still has a value of `'closed'`

[image: 2Cookies]

Here is a fiddle to my whole code minus the html for the advertisement. I don't know if jsfiddle allows you to create cookies or not so I'm not sure if this will work

https://jsfiddle.net/x43nbbmk/

Comment: if you are using cookies only for client side actions i'll suggest to try using localStorage instead.

Comment: Check your spelling of  'Advertisement' vs 'Advertistement' in CloseCookieAdvertisement

Comment: @Gary Wow. I feel dumb now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your spelling of 'Advertisement' vs 'Advertistement' in CloseCookieAdvertisement